# Cocoa protocol for cut, copy and paste actions

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

Is there any protocol in Cocoa implementing standard actions for cut: copy paste:, like there is UIResponderStandardEditActions for UIKit?

I would like to do something like this without implementing delete(_:) in this class, with the new Swift3 #selector:

```
override func supplementalTarget(forAction action: Selector, sender: Any?) -> Any? {

    switch action{
        case #selector(delete(_:)):
             return outlineView.delegate

        default:
            return nextResponder
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own protocol:

```
@objc protocol MyStandardActionProtocol {
    func cut(_: Any)
    func copy(_: Any)
    func paste(_: Any)
}
```

And use `#selector` like:

```
override func supplementalTarget(forAction action: Selector, sender: Any?) -> Any? {
    switch action{
    case #selector(MyStandardActionProtocol.cut(_:)):
        return ...
    //...
    default:
        return nextResponder
    }
}
```

Type information is not included in `Selector` instances, so this will work even if no classes conform to the protocol.